# Django response return empty array

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to retrieve a list from django class based views and i'm getting the below output in my response

```
[{},{}]
```

The model currently has two items in it.

below is my views.py

```
class CategoryList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer,TemplateHTMLRenderer,BrowsableAPIRenderer)
    template_name = 'create.html'
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

below is my ajax call:

```
  function getcategories(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/billing/categories',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      crossDomain:true,

      success : function(json){
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i ++){
        $('#category-row').append('<td>'+json[i].category + '</td>');
        console.log('success');
        console.log(json.length);
      }
    },
      error : function(){
        console.log('there was an error with category-get');
      }
    });

  };
```

where am I going wrong?

Comment: Post the code for serializer also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably in your serializer class. It doesn't know how to convert your model into json. It is getting a list of two items, but since it cannot convert them it just puts an empty object.

Comment: Yea .. pretty much spot on .. minor mistake .. thanks